# How to add certificate on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, proxy, certificate

[image]

I want to add an certificate on my Ubuntu, the goagent.crt in the image.

I copy it to /usr/share/ca-certificates/ , and excute "sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates", and the image above showed up.
I find that the goagent.crt is not selected! After I press enter, the certificates update seems not work.

Is there any ideas to select the goagent.crt in this dialog? How to  add a "*" before goagent.crt?

Answer (score 8):

Just press *Space* and your certificate is marked for installation.

Comment: The amount of places I had to search for someone to mention how to select a certificate pushed me to the edge. THANK YOU.